# VB.NET System.NullReferenceException

Tags: vb.net, dataset, nullreferenceexception

I have a VB.NET program that builds multiple datasets from 10 different databases.

I am getting this Exception:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object referenced not set to an 
instance of an object:
```

This error happens on the following lines:

```
Me.OverTableAdapter.Adapter.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout = 60000
Me.OverTableAdapter.Fill(Me.Dataset.Over, TodayDt, TodayEnd)
```

What does this Exception mean?

Comment: You should attach a debugger and see which of the objects in Me.OverTableAdapter.Adapter.SelectCommand is null.

Comment: So this is a strongly typed dataset and `OverTableAdapter` is an autogenerated `TableAdapter`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well if it's failing on this line:

```
Me.OverTableAdapter.Adapter.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout = 60000
```

Then either:

- `Me.OverTableAdapter` is `Nothing`
- `Me.OverTableAdapter.Adapter` is `Nothing`
- `Me.OverTableAdapter.SelectCommand` is `Nothing`

(The second line you've shown us is irrelevant, as you're not getting that far.)

We can't tell based on what you've shown us, but you should be able to find out either in a debugger or by adding diagnostic logging.

Once you've worked out *why* it's failing, fixing it should be easy - it's almost certainly just a matter of initializing it properly. Compare your initialization of this adapter with the initialization of the other ones.

Comment: It's not selecting anything, it's simply telling the program to increase the timeout of this specific adapter fill... It's assigned the connection string earlier in the program, however as I stated earlier, it's identical to the other 10... I assign the database connection string differently in each section, and then cycle through and collect the results using the same code.

Comment: @Shmewnix: I didn't say it was selecting anything. I said that one of those expressions is `Nothing`. And I strongly suspect it *isn't* actually identical to the other 10. I strongly suspect you've got a typo somewhere, but we can't tell what as you've only shown us a tiny piece of code. As I said, you should go in with a debugger and work out which expression is null and why.

Comment: I believe I found the issue.  I Fill the datasets information locally from the first call of the LOCAL database.  I did not assign "overtableadapter" anything in the first call, locally, therefor it was NULL when calling for it initially in this external database.  The internal database does not have a timeout call, because it's a local databases, and never times out.  Thank You.

Answer (score 2):

The reason for this exception is that the `SelectCommand` will be inititalized from `TableAdapter.Fill` and not before. So when you try to change the `Timeout` before you get the `NullReferenceException`.

You can extend the `TableAdapter` by creating the partial class in a separate file than the `designer.vb/designer.cs`.

```
Namespace DataSet1TableAdapters

    Partial Public Class OverTableAdapter
        Public Property CommandTimeout As System.Int32
            Get
                If Me.CommandCollection Is Nothing OrElse Me.CommandCollection.Length = 0 Then
                    Return -1
                Else
                    Return Me.CommandCollection(0).CommandTimeout
                End If
            End Get
            Set(value As System.Int32)
                If Not Me.CommandCollection Is Nothing Then
                    For Each cmd In Me.CommandCollection
                        cmd.CommandTimeout = value
                    Next
                End If
            End Set
        End Property
    End Class

End Namespace
```

Now you can use this property instead after you've created an instance of the adapter.

Comment: This is incorrect.  It's the 4th selectcommand, followed by Fill for this particular database.  If it's any other way... it times out. (again this works for all other databases in the program).

Comment: @Shmewnix: What means _"it's the 4th SelectCommand"_? A `TableAdapter` has only one `SelectCommand` and that is initialized from the methods which select rows. That can be `Fill`, `GetData` or a custom query which returns rows. However, one of these must be executed, otherwise the `SelectCommand`(which is `protected` btw) is `Nothing/null`. But even if it is not null it'll be overridden on every method call from the appropriate command. That's why my property above sets all command's `CommandTimeouts`.

Comment: You are correct.  Your info was Helpful.